# SignalR dotnet core authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR) nuget package with [`Bazinga.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bazinga.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic) which adds basic authentication to dotnet core. My C# SignalR client connects when there is no authentication, but when I add `AuthorizeAttribute` it connects by http and http request header gets authenticated successfully but the Socket does not authenticate probably because there is no header in socket messages.

So I am wondering how should I pass a token or something to authenticated socket connection or is there a example code that I can follow. I think I should pass a random token to just authenticated user and the user needs to constantly pass the token in messages.

[Client project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/afsneajippv6vfx/SignalRClient.zip?dl=0), [Server project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jy2wkc8x79e9ku3/SymmetricCryptoChatRoom.zip?dl=0)

**Server:**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Bazinga.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic;
using Domainlogic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin();
            }));

            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddAuthentication(BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddBasicAuthentication(credentials => Task.FromResult(
                    credentials.username == "SomeUserName"
                    && credentials.password == "SomePassword"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseCors(CorsConstants.AnyOrigin);

            app.UseFileServer();

            app.UseSignalR(route => { route.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat"); });

            app.UseAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server hub:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace Domainlogic
{
    public class MessagePayload
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    }

    [Authorize]
    public class MessageHub : Hub
    {   
        // connected IDs
        private static readonly HashSet<string> ConnectedIds = new HashSet<string>();

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendAction", "joined", ConnectedIds.Count);
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
        {
            ConnectedIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendAction", "left", ConnectedIds.Count);
        }

        public async Task Send(MessagePayload message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage", message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SignalRClient
{
    public class MessagePayload
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var credential = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("SomeUserName" + ":" + "SomePassword"));

            //Set connection
            var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/chat", options =>
                {
                    options.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {credential}");
                })
                .AddJsonProtocol()
                .Build();

            connection.On<MessagePayload>("SendMessage", param =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(param.Message);
            });

            connection.StartAsync().Wait();

            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            int i = 0;

            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {
                connection.InvokeAsync<MessagePayload>("Send", new MessagePayload()
                {
                    Message = "Some message: " + i++
                });
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);


            Console.Read();
            connection.StopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to "davidfowl" on GitHub, the solution was moving `UseAuthentication` above the `UseSignalR`.

**Source**: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2316

Instead of:

```
app.UseSignalR(route => { route.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat"); });

app.UseAuthentication();
```

Use this:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseSignalR(route => { route.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat"); });
```

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation!?!?

Comment: I also had to add app.UseAuthorization(); between app.UseAuthentication(); and app.UseSignalR (in my case, app.UseEndpoints), in the configure section, in order for it to work, otherwise it was giving an error about a middleware.

Comment: Also this line:
app.UseSignalR(route => { route.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat"); });
Should be replaced by:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat");
});
According to the documentations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/signalr-usesignalr-useconnections-removed

Answer (score -2):

To solve this I had to store in server cache with a Dictionary the token of the user with the connectionId. That because in the hub I don't have control over the session.

So every time a user is connected with the hub I exposed and endpoint which receives the connectionId and the token of the user. When a request is handle by the Hub I know by the connection which is the user authenticated.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Route("{connectionId}")]
public IActionResult Post(string connectionId)
{
    this.hubConnectionService.AddConnection(connectionId, this.workContext.CurrentUserId);
    return this.Ok();
}
```

Hub

```
public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    this.hubConnectionService.RemoveConnection(this.Context.ConnectionId);
    return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```